# django sessionid, csrrftoken and vue axios

Tags: django, vue.js, csrf, axios, sessionid

I have a question about using vue axios frontend and Django backend in cors-domain environment.

My cookie can use set-Cookie sessionid and csrftoken but frontend can't get these parameters to save to my document. 
If I use my chrome explorer, the application cookie is empty but I can find the cookie in response cookie header. 
But I won't use this csrftoken to backend verify in other POST AJAX, how can I resolve it to verify? 
I try a lot of settings, but not work in using `@csrf_protect` function, though just remove it and use `@csrf_exempt` can work.
**How can I keep csrftoken work in this situation?**

Thanks.

The followings are what I use settings.

**axios settings**

```
axios.defaults.headers.get['Accept'] = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
```

**Django settings**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-CSRFToken',
    'X-CSRFToken',
    'csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```